# How to optimise an Entity framework query with 3 includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 5 on .Net 4

I have the following model:

```
public class Order
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }

    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingCost { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Addressee { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

and model configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(x => x.OrderLines).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(x => x.BillingAddress).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(x => x.DeliveryAddress).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

when I run the following query I get sql with **19 Joins** which seems excessive for the simple relationship

```
context.Orders
       .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId)
       .Include(x => x.OrderLines)
       .Include(x => x.BillingAddress)
       .Include(x => x.DeliveryAddress)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different to format the linq query to optimize the produced SQL?

EDIT:

This is the actual query: https://gist.github.com/4278014

Comment: 19?? That really doesn't sound right!  HAve you got the SQL it made?

Comment: @JustinHarvey I added the query to the question.

Comment: That is one awesome query for sure.  Remove all 3 includes and check the SQL again.  If it looks normal, then add the includes back in one by one to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `WithOptionalDependent` on the billing and delivery addresses. This creates a 1:1 relationship between the address and the order, even though the tables are set up for a 1:many relationship.

If you change the configuration to use `WithMany` instead:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(x => x.OrderLines).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(x => x.BillingAddress).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(x => x.DeliveryAddress).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

the query is much simpler, and is essentially equivalent to:

```
...
FROM [Orders]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Addresses] As B ON [Orders].[BillingAddress_Id] = B.[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Addresses] As D ON [Orders].[DeliveryAddress_Id] = D.[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [OrderLines] ON [Orders].[Id] = [OrderLines].[Order_Id]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as you said. Here is the new query: https://gist.github.com/4283933